# Cypress - Filter non zeros from table td

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am pretty new to cypress have been using it while for integration test and came across one issue where I want to filter the contents of table i.e. based on 'td'. I have used the callback for getting the 'td's from rows and tried to use the promise and then select it but it seems not working.

```
 cy.get($trs).find('td:nth-child(9)').then(($tds)=>{
            cy.get($tds)
              .should('not.have.value',0)
              .first()

          })
```

[image]
The td don't have any class name or attribute attached to it otherwise could have used `not()` or `filter()`
Anyway, has anyone got any suggestions ?

Comment: I can't look into it more now but on first sight, there's a thing popping in my eyes - `should` assertion should always be before DOM selector. Means you need to change order of your `first` and `should` commands... do `cy.get($tds).first().should('not.have.value',0)`...Not saying it will fix your overall problem, it just caught my eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks to the [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/#contains1) - I've found a performance friendly solution.

```
 cy.get($trs).find('td:nth-child(9)').each(($td) => {  
                    cy.get($td).not(':contains("0")')  // This is the key :)
                        .first().parent('tr')
                        // do your stuffs
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can share the html source and what value you want to check in your screenshot it would be great.

I assume you want to find the elment in the screenshot. You can use [each](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html) to loop the elements in your highlight in the screenshot.

```
    cy.get('tr').find('td:nth-child(9)').each(($td)=>{
        cy.wrap($td).invoke('text').then(($text)=> {
            if ($text !== "0")  
                //do something here
                {console.log($text)}
        })
    })
```

Comment: well, is there any way to skip the loop ?, the rows in the table could be more so performance wise can I have a better solution ?

Comment: In your screenshot you have 4 values to check. How can you not use a loop to check more than one value? Performance wise can you specify how many rows are we checking?

Comment: It is dynamic, ranging from 5 to 1000. However I've found a better solution, posting it out here